# Offsetting rotated arrow SVG markers in Leaflet (exported with QGIS2Web)

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I have a map exported from QGIS (3.34 Prizren) as leaflet via QGIS2Web plugin. The map has 3 layers (identical data) but 2 are displayed as arrow SVG markers and 1 is displayed as points. Left arrows are blue and right are red. I created these 3 layers in QGIS and then exported.

[image]

In the [leaflet code](https://github.com/tabeh0udai/leaflet-arrows/blob/main/index.html), I have applied rotation based on a the `lhead` field and am now trying to offset the arrows so that they appear to be coming out of the point. I need them to be offset while respecting the angle that they are rotated to (based on values lhead & rhead fields). In other words, I cannot simply offset everything a bit in the X and Y directions because the arrows must still be rotated to their respective angles, and these differ for each point.
I have tried using the iconAnchor property in the arrow marker functions like so:

````
function style_left_2_0(feature) {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_left_2',
                rotationAngle: feature.properties['lhead'] || 0, 
                rotationOrigin: 'center center',
                icon: L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'markers/left_2.svg',
                    iconSize: [32.68, 32.68],
                    iconAnchor: [32.34, 32.34]
                }),
                interactive: false,
            };
        }```
````

but this just shifts all of the blue left arrows up & to the left. I want them to be offset to the left while respecting their rotation. (ex. this left arrow’s angle is 279°, so I want it to be offset along this angle rather than along a regular horizontal plane).

[image]

This is what I want the end result to look like, just as I've configured in QGIS: arrows coming out of the point and offset while respecting their respective angles.

[image]

LINK TO FULL CODE: https://github.com/tabeh0udai/leaflet-arrows/blob/main/index.html

Comment: why don't you create a unique svg icon, with both mirrored arrows and the dot in the center?  you would then just need to define a rotation angle as you have already done to achieve the result, or am I wrong?

Comment: @andreaordonselli Thanks for your input, thats a nice simple solution that i'll keep in mind for the future. Although they appear similar in my images, the angles are different for each point so I'd have to create a bunch of SVGs

Answer (score 2):

Since Leaflet has no built in rotation for markers, [Leaflet.RotatedMarker](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker) plugin has to be used for marker rotation.

To get desired combined marker, right values have to be used for `iconAnchor` option when creating arrow icons. If both of original SVG icons point up (north) like this:
[image]
[image]

then `x` value for `iconAnchor` option has to be half of icon width and `y` value has to be icon height plus radius of the circle between arrows. Rotation angle of the second arrow has to be 180 greater than for the first one.

Code for creating combined marker could then look something like this:

```
const iconWidth = 22;
const iconHeight = 30;
const circleRadius = 8;

var blueIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/arrow-up-blue.svg',
  iconSize: [iconWidth, iconHeight],
  iconAnchor: [(iconWidth / 2), (iconHeight + circleRadius)],
});
var redIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/arrow-up-red.svg',
  iconSize: [iconWidth, iconHeight],
  iconAnchor: [(iconWidth / 2), (iconHeight + circleRadius)],
});

function placeRotatedSymbol(coords, angle) {
  L.marker(coords, {
    icon: blueIcon,
    rotationAngle: angle,
  }).addTo(map);
  L.marker(coords, {
    icon: redIcon,
    rotationAngle: (angle + 180),
  }).addTo(map);
  L.circleMarker(coords, {
    pane: 'tooltipPane',
    radius: circleRadius,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    weight: 1,
    fill: true,
    fillColor: '#DBA044',
    fillOpacity: 1
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

Call `placeRotatedSymbol([48.8631169, 2.3708919], 72);` would then give the following combined marker:

[image]

Comment: great answer. thank you for your support.

Comment: I'm not the creator of the question so I can't mark it as correct, in any case I voted for it because I think it is actually correct

Comment: @andreaordonselli Ups, sorry, I assumed it on the basis of comment content.